# Using isobmff github. Make fmp4 file

Tags: mp4, h.264, fmp4

Using isobmff github. I am trying to Make Avc to fmp4 file.
Now I am using
Link : https://github.com/MPEGGroup/isobmff
this C Library for isobmff.
I want to Make fmp4 file and There is similar case of make fmp4 file.
Link : https://github.com/MPEGGroup/isobmff/blob/master/test/test_sample_groups.cpp
This example is using Sample Group. (It make fmp4 with sample group box)
My question is that is it possible to make fmp4 without Sample Group?
If possible, Plesae give me some example code
Thank you.